# pyodbc - inserting selected rows (access mdb)

Tags: sql, ms-access, pyodbc

When inserting selected records / rows from an Access .mdb table, I find a "`Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502)`" on line 23 of this code block.

What I want to happen is to

1. Create a table '65001'
2. Select the first 65000 rows from table 'LMR_Combined'
3. Insert those selected rows into the newly created '65001' table.

What syntax mistake is in this INSERT INTO statement that's preventing successful execution?

```
import pyodbc
DBFile = r'C:\Python27\FCC_Processing\LMR Combined.mdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+DBFile)

cursor = conn.cursor()


# Creates a table "65001" in the MDB that matches the schema of table "LMR_Combined"
string = "CREATE TABLE 65001(OBJECTID integer, Unique_ID varchar(255), LICENSEE_NAME varchar(255))"

cursor.execute(string)

# Selects 65000 records from table "LMR_Combined"
cursor.execute('select OBJECTID, Unique_ID, LICENSEE_NAME from LMR_Combined where OBJECTID > 0 and OBJECTID < 65001')

row = cursor.fetchone()

# For debugging, print a line
if row:
    print row

# Inserts the 65000 rows into the new table "65001"
cursor.execute('insert OBJECTID, Unique_ID, LICENSEE_NAME into 65001')

conn.commit()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider whether it is sufficient to create and populate your *65001* table with a [SELECT...INTO Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208934%28v=office.12%29.aspx):

```sql
SELECT OBJECTID, Unique_ID, LICENSEE_NAME
INTO [65001]
FROM LMR_Combined
WHERE OBJECTID > 0 AND OBJECTID < 65001;
```

If you need different data types than `SELECT...INTO` gives you, execute your `CREATE TABLE` and then execute this `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO [65001] (OBJECTID, Unique_ID, LICENSEE_NAME)
SELECT OBJECTID, Unique_ID, LICENSEE_NAME
FROM LMR_Combined
WHERE OBJECTID > 0 AND OBJECTID < 65001;
```

Comment: Thanks HansUp - that SELECT INTO statement was perfect. For searchers: The pyodbc-specific code I actually used was `cursor.execute('SELECT OBJECTID, Unique_ID, LICENSEE_NAME into [65001] from LMR_Combined where OBJECTID > 0 AND OBJECTID <65001')`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong.

The right way to insert data in a table is:

```
insert into table1 (field1, field2, ...)
select ...
```

Or:

```
insert into table1(field1, field2, ...)
values (value1, value2, ...)
```